# duplicated element in xml where vb class has a list of property when exporting as serialize to xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, class, serialization, xml-serialization

I have a class defined as below:

```
Public Class details
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property rooms As New List(Of rooms)
End Class

Public Class rooms
    Public Property room_name As String
    Public Property room_description As String
End Class
```

Its house details that has multiple rooms per house.

I am coding it as follows:

```
Dim clsPDts As New details
clsPDts.description = "test property name"
Dim tmpRoom As New rooms
tmpRoom.room_name = "BEDROOM ONE"
tmpRoom.room_description = "Fitted wardrobes with mirror sliding doors"
clsPDts.details.rooms.Add(tmpRoom)
```

Then outputting as follows:

```
Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter("D:\Product.xml")
Dim x As New XmlSerializer(clsPDts.GetType)
x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, clsPDts)
objStreamWriter.Close()
```

The XML file should be as below as that's the format it MUST BE:

```
<details>
    <description>A Two Bedroomed Second Floor Apartment Situated Within this Seafront Development.</description>
    <rooms>
      <room_name>COMMUNAL HALLWAY</room_name>
      <room_description>Communal entrance door with entry phone system.</room_description>
    </rooms>
    <rooms>
      <room_name>ENTRANCE HALL</room_name>
      <room_description>Personal entrance door. Built-in airing cupboard, storage heater.</room_description>
    </rooms>
    <rooms>
      <room_name>BEDROOM ONE</room_name>
      <room_description>Fitted wardrobes with mirror fronted sliding doors</room_description>
    </rooms>
</details>
```

But its currently coming out as below with the extra room element around the other multiple rooms:

```
<details>
  <description>A Two Bedroomed Second Floor Apartment Situated Within this Seafront Development.</description>
  <rooms>
    <rooms>
      <room_name>COMMUNAL HALLWAY</room_name>
      <room_description>Communal entrance door with entry phone system.</room_description>
    </rooms>
    <rooms>
      <room_name>ENTRANCE HALL</room_name>
      <room_description>Personal entrance door. Built-in airing cupboard, storage heater.</room_description>
    </rooms>
    <rooms>
      <room_name>BEDROOM ONE</room_name>
      <room_description>Fitted wardrobes with mirror fronted sliding doors</room_description>
    </rooms>
  </rooms>
</details>
```

I am unsure how i can get rid of the extra outer  element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the Tag as XmlElement like in the code below

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

    End Sub

End Module

<XmlRoot("details")>
Public Class details
    <XmlElement("description")>
    Public Property description As String
    <XmlElement("rooms")>
    Public Property rooms As New List(Of rooms)
End Class

<XmlRoot("rooms")>
Public Class rooms
    <XmlElement("room_name")>
    Public Property room_name As String
    <XmlElement("room_decription")>
    Public Property room_description As String
End Class
```